# Lack of memory for array addresses

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory, memory-leaks

I'm having an real time application which generates some values to be processed.
In one of the functions that I'm using, I'm declaring every time, not as global functions what is follow:

```
#define BUFFER 25
double A[BUFFER];
double B[BUFFER];
double C[BUFFER];
double TOTAL[BUFFER];
double ERRORS[BUFFER];
```

But it seems that it's allocating some pointers/addresses to all of the array values without getting rid of them as soon as their treatments are done.

If I consider that the project is using the function which contains the above declarations, and my project is updating new values every one second, for 30 minutes: thus,
**25*5*60*30=225K useless memories are used**

How to get rid of them everytime? I'm having a lack of memory usage and don't want my program to crash because of non used memories!

Comment: If the above code is your actual code, the arrays are created on the stack and will be destroyed (and their memory freed) when the function exits.

Comment: @Angew How to proove it?

Comment: The language standard says so. Who do you need to prove it to?

Comment: @SebastianRedl  to myself!

Comment: @M.Mellouli read language standard for prove it to yourself...

Comment: Your 225 would need to be multiplied by sizeof(double) to be in bytes

Comment: @M.Mellouli Your condescending attitude is uncalled for.

Comment: @M.Mellouli If you need "proof," refer to `ISO/IEC 14882:2011` (a.k.a. C++11 standard) `[basic.stc]`, especially `[basic.stc.auto]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As these are stack-allocated, they *will* be cleared once your function exists.

If you're concerned about this creation / destruction happening each time you use the function then put this in your function instead:

```
static double A[BUFFER];
static double B[BUFFER];
static double C[BUFFER];
static double TOTAL[BUFFER];
static double ERRORS[BUFFER];
```

It's not very good programming practice (for starters it is extremely single-threaded!) but it will mean that the arrays are only created once and destroyed once your program exits.

But, back to your problem, I really can't see how this can be the cause of any memory problems you have: the amount you are consuming is tiny.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that if five arrays of five doubles is causing you to be out of memory, you are using a machine without much memory. Alternatively, it might be pushing you over the edge, because something else is using all the memory. Is it your program? If so, profile it.